# How to stop Windows 8 default antivirus from scanning executables that I build in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, antivirus

I'm using Visual Studio to build my C++ projects. I've been noticing that as I build my project, the `Windows Defender Service` kicks in and begins scanning it even before the executable is even linked:

[image]

So sometimes that results in the following error:

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open .\Debug/MyProjName.exe for
>   writing

which makes me rebuild it again, that usually succeeds.

Another annoyance is that when I run a freshly built executable for the first time, the same antimalware service begins scanning it, which delays it for about 5-10 seconds. This of course is not an issue for a single run, but becomes an annoyance once you do it many times over (during a debugging process.)

So I'm curious if there's a way to make it stop scanning a certain folder?

Comment: I believe you can add directories to be ignored in Windows Defender's settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Guide with images from Microsoft here.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/wiki/protect_defender-protect_scanning/how-to-exclude-a-filefolder-from-windows-defender/f32ee18f-a012-4f02-8611-0737570e8eee)

You go to settings, excluded files and locations, and add the desired directories to exclude.

Comment: Oh great. I was looking for its icon in the system tray like it used to be in Win7. I didn't know that they moved it to CP... Oops. Thanks!